# Why would a hive query with no order by/sort by clause end up with a single reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, reducers

I have a simple query associated with a streaming job that does NOT have an order by statement in it.

```
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=100;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=100;
set hive.exec.max.created.files=100;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set mapred.reduce.tasks=20;
add file /home/devo/c1166313/pafvalid.py ;
add file /home/devo/c1166313/paf-rules.properties ;
from
 (from  
   (select * from mz_paf_errors_dummy_v) p
select transform (p.*)  row format delimited fields terminated by '|' 
using 'pafvalid.py paf-rules.properties 10'
as (<column list>)
row format delimited fields terminated by '|' )  b
insert overwrite table mytab partition (passfail, batch_sk) select <col list>;
```

This is a medium size cluster (few tens of machines) and the number of mappers is over two thousand.  Why would a single reducer be required?

```
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
```

Comment: Sounds strange as you'd set `mapter.reduce.tasks` that should override any other setting. Try checking `hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` parameter as the number of reducers by default is calculated in the following way : `# reducers = (# bytes of input to mappers) / (hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer)` - What is the size of your output?

Comment: Hmm, nice suggestion, hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=268435456 I will keep in mind if see single reducers again. I believe in this case we had far more data, but will keep this in mind.